# How to use sticky css in Fancybox 3.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-3

I am building a matching quiz for a class assignment using bootstrap columns and rows inside of a fancybox lightbox. I would like to use `position: sticky;` to fix one of my columns in place as I scroll. Unfortunately,

```
 position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
```

does not seem to do the job.

My browser's developer's tools indicate that these properties are not being overwritten, even when the top of the column div passes beyond the top of the window. I've tried fixing the height of the column, but that did not seem to work.

For what it's worth, I have used `position: sticky;` on other bootstrap columns without issue.

Here is a codepen that captures the basics of what I am trying to do. The div I am trying to sticky is called #namesBox. I'd like it to stay in place as the user scrolls down the rest of the fancybox.

https://codepen.io/abrezey/pen/pBaYwo

Is there a specific css property I need to add or something I need to change in the fancybox default settings to allow this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you provide some sample/demo? I believe that if you can make your element "sticky", then there is no reason it would not work inside fancybox.

Comment: Hi, @Janis. Just added in a codepen link.

Comment: You code seems to be so unnecessary complex that I am not sure I want to debug that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've already moved on from this but anyone stumbling across this, `position: sticky` will not work as expected with an ancestor with any value of `overflow` other than `visible`. As fancybox (and most lightbox solutions) add `overflow: hidden` to the body element, sticky will not work.

As far as I am aware there is no way around this besides removing the `overflow: hidden` rule on the body element and all other ancestors. This in practice does not work as fancybox relies upon several nested overflow rules in order to provide scrolling within its modals.

Source: https://uxdesign.cc/position-stuck-96c9f55d9526